# react-dropzone-uploader how to display already uploaded files from a react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, dropzone, react-dropzone

I am currently using RDU(react-dropzone-uploader) to upload files to the server, I am saving the uploaded files in a react state. I am trying to figure out how to display the already uploaded files as part of the preview on the dropzone from the react state.

I have tried going through a list of props in the documentation.

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/props

I found `initialFiles` prop but it is auto uploading the provided input array of files.

any help is appreciated

Comment: are you able to find any solution until now

Comment: Found any solution ?

Comment: Still a valid question

Answer (score 0):

The custom layout feature allows you to customize the full display. There's a prop called `LayoutComponent`. Using this, you can inject displays for any files that were uploaded previously, in addition to the `previews` provided via props.

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/customization#custom-layout

If you want your custom preview displays and the dropzone preview displays to match, you can also define a custom preview component. There's a prop called `PreviewComponent`.

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/customization#default-components